# Insert column specific NaN and drop rows depending on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert, nan

I have performed several hypothetical tests on insects. I want to drop rows with low **result_1 values of 'less than 10'** which I consider not to be significant, but would like to leave a NaN in value a **single row** to show which test was performed and on which insect.

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import numpy as np

A = Series(['A','A','B','B','B','C'])
B = Series(['ant','flea','flea','spider','spider','flea'])
C = Series([88,77,1,3,2,67])
D = Series(np.random.randn(6))

df = DataFrame({'test':A.values,'insect':B.values,
            'result_1':C.values,'result_2':D.values},
           columns=['test','insect','result_1','result_2'])
df
```

So the original Dataframe looks like this:

[image]

And because indexes 2,3 and 4 have **results_1** values <10, I would like to drop all those rows with the caveat that one row is left (with NaN in **both** results columns) to show that Test B was performed on the flea (index2), and one row should be left to show that indeed test B was performed on a spider (of indexes 3 and 4, one needs to be dropped and the other needs an NaN inserted in the results columns).

So, the resulting Dataframe should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
#add NaN by condition
df.loc[df.result_1 < 10, ['result_1','result_2']] = np.nan 
#drop duplicated by column insect
df[df.result_1.isnull()] = df[df.result_1.isnull()].drop_duplicates(subset='insect')
df = df.dropna(how='all')
print (df)
  test  insect  result_1  result_2
0    A     ant      88.0 -0.037844
1    A    flea      77.0 -1.088879
2    B    flea       NaN       NaN
3    B  spider       NaN       NaN
5    C    flea      67.0  1.455632
```

Another solution with finding relevant index and then [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) row with this `index`:

```
mask = df.result_1 < 10

df.loc[mask, ['result_1','result_2']] = np.nan 
a = df[mask].duplicated(subset='insect')
print (a)
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool

a = a[a].index
df = df.drop(a)
print (df)
  test  insect  result_1  result_2
0    A     ant      88.0 -0.176274
1    A    flea      77.0 -0.123691
2    B    flea       NaN       NaN
3    B  spider       NaN       NaN
5    C    flea      67.0 -0.310655
```